Eclipse is not fully switching to "Dark Theme/Mode"
I'm having an issue with my Eclipse. I'm using Windows 11, but I was forced to reformat it recently due to my previous NVME failing.
After reinstalling Windows and installing all drivers and updates, I installed Eclipse and noticed that when I switch Eclipse to Dark Mode, the taskbar isn't in Dark Mode, nor is the initial workspace selection screen. See some images below:



Given that, I thought it might be because I was using a Dark Theme that comes with DevStyle.
After installing the plugin, I noticed that even though it darkened some areas, the issue still wasn't resolved.

I’ve already installed JRE 23 and JDK 17, but the issue wasn’t resolved.
I saw that others have encountered this problem before, and it was supposed to be fixed in the 2020 version, but I’m using the 2024-09 version.
I even tried following the steps from the link below:

Dark mode in Eclipse changes the color of the drop down menu text making it unreadable. How do I fix this?

I switched back to Light Mode and then back to Dark, but it still didn’t solve the problem.
Note: When I’m using the DevStyle theme, I always get the error below, and I have to end the task in Task Manager because of it.

So... Am I forgetting something? Is there something else I need to update? I don’t know what else to do since before, I didn’t have to do anything— I just downloaded Eclipse and started using it.
The difference is that instead of using a new version, I brought over the one I had on my old machine, which was a ZIP version. Since I unfortunately lost that version, I had to reconfigure everything from scratch, and this time I decided to download the executable instead of using the ZIP version.
Note: I also tried using the ZIP version, and the error is still the same.
Note: I'm using Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
What I'm hoping to resolve is getting my Eclipse to fully switch to Dark Mode. From what I see, what’s happening for me is not normal behavior.

Windows menus are styled in the dark theme

